# Edit Gboard dictionary from a PC or the web

Tags: gboard, dictionary, text-input

I am using the dictionary in the Gboard app as a text expander app. Is there a way I can add words or edit the dictionary words from a PC?

The reason that I want to do this is because I do not want to introduce a typo.